# How search in UITableView with Array of model

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to search for some data in the table view using the search bar, but when I try to find data in my model, I'm not able to search that data.
I made a expand table view cell and created a search bar for searching data, but still I can't search the data in the model. How can I achieve that?

my code is here:

```
import UIKit

protocol SelectCurrencyViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func selectedCurrency(_ curency: CurrencyModel)
}

final class SelectCurrencyViewController: UIViewController {
    
    weak var delegate: SelectCurrencyViewControllerDelegate?
    
    
    //MARK: - Private properties
    
    private let currencyCellIdentifier = "currencyCell"
    private let currencyArray = [CurrencyModel(shortName: "RUB", fullName: "Russian ruble"),
                                 CurrencyModel(shortName: "USD", fullName: "US Dollar"),
                                 CurrencyModel(shortName: "EUR", fullName: "Euro")]
    
    
    //MARK: - UI elements
    
    private let currencyTableView = UITableView()
    private let searchBarCurrency = UISearchBar()
    
    
    //MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - Private methods
    
    private func setupUI() {
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        view.addSubview(searchBarCurrency)
        view.addSubview(currencyTableView)
        settingsSearchbar()
        settingsCurrencyTableView()
        setConstraints()
    }
    
    private func settingsSearchbar() {
        searchBarCurrency.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        searchBarCurrency.delegate = self
    }
    
    private func settingsCurrencyTableView() {
        currencyTableView.dataSource = self
        currencyTableView.delegate = self
        currencyTableView.register(CustomCurrencyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: currencyCellIdentifier)
        currencyTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    
    private func setConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            searchBarCurrency.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            searchBarCurrency.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            searchBarCurrency.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            
            currencyTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchBarCurrency.bottomAnchor),
            currencyTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            currencyTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            currencyTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
}


//MARK: - UISearchBarDelegate
extension SelectCurrencyViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        print(searchText)
    }
}


//MARK: - UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
extension SelectCurrencyViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        currencyArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: currencyCellIdentifier,
                                                 for: indexPath) as? CustomCurrencyCell
        cell?.configure(shortName: currencyArray[indexPath.row].shortName,
                        fullName: currencyArray[indexPath.row].fullName)
        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.selectedCurrency(currencyArray[indexPath.row])
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

my code of CustomCell here:

```
import UIKit

final class CustomCurrencyCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    //MARK: - UI Elements
    
    private let currencyBoldLabel = UILabel()
    private let currencyNormalFullLabel = UILabel()
    
    
    //MARK: - Life Cycle
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupUI()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - Configure
    
    func configure(shortName: String, fullName: String) {
        currencyBoldLabel.text = shortName
        currencyNormalFullLabel.text = fullName
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - Private methods
    
    private func setupUI() {
        addSubview(currencyBoldLabel)
        addSubview(currencyNormalFullLabel)
        settingsCurrencyBoldLabel()
        setConstraints()
    }
    
    private func settingsCurrencyBoldLabel() {
        currencyBoldLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        currencyBoldLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)
    }
    
    private func setConstraints() {
        currencyNormalFullLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            currencyBoldLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            currencyBoldLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            
            currencyNormalFullLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            currencyNormalFullLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: currencyBoldLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 8)
        ])
    }
}
```

and code of my Model:

```
import Foundation

struct CurrencyModel {
    let shortName: String
    let fullName: String
}
```

I try this add search data

```
private var searchDate = [CurrencyModel]()
```

and in searchBarDelegate try this:

```
extension SelectCurrencyViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
         searchDate = searchText.isEmpty ? currencyArray : currencyArray.filter {$0.fullName.contains(searchText)}
        currencyTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Idk how cast my cell in `cellForRowAt`, cause I used `configure`
and if I trying

```
cell?.currencyNormalFullLabel.text = searchDate[indexPath.row].fullName
```

my app crashed

Comment: SearchDate should be your data source, in table view delegate instead of currency array use searchDate, also initialise searchDate similar to currencyArray

Comment: @vignesh Anyway my app crashed with `Fatal error: Index out of range` in `cell?.currencyNormalFullLabel.text = searchDate[indexPath.row].fullName
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem:
In `viewDidLoad` I’m add

```
filtredData = currencyArray
```

and in `numberOfRowsInSection` change like this:

```
    extension SelectCurrencyViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        filtredData.count
    }
```

and cast my cell like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: currencyCellIdentifier,
                                                 for: indexPath) as? CustomCurrencyCell
        cell?.configure(shortName: filtredData[indexPath.row].shortName,
                        fullName: filtredData[indexPath.row].fullName)
        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
    }
```

and finally edit my filter method:

```
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filtredData = []
        
        if searchText == "" {
            filtredData = currencyArray
        }
            
        for word in currencyArray {
            if word.fullName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) ||
                word.shortName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
                filtredData.append(word)
            }
        }
        self.currencyTableView.reloadData()
    }
```